# alignment problem under new environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments

i have defined a new environment called "example"

```
 \newenvironment{ex}{\begin{quote}%
    \refstepcounter{examplecounter}%
  \textbf{Example \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{examplecounter}}%
  \quad
}{%
\end{quote}%
}
```

However the outcome would be like that

```
Example 1.2 The function x blah blah blah...(till the right of the page)
*AND it continues here....
```

What i want is this... the (AND) will align exactly where the "The" words starts in the 1st line...

```
Example 1.2 The function x blah blah blah...(till the right of the page)
            *AND it continues here....
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Should the rest of the example content all be indented according to your display, even if you have multiple paragraphs in the example? What about `Example 1.11` (double-digit numbering)?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcounter{examplecounter}[chapter]
 \newenvironment{ex}{%
    \refstepcounter{examplecounter}%
   \list{}{%
    \rightmargin\leftmargin
    \settowidth\labelwidth{Example \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{examplecounter}}%
    }
  \item[Example \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{examplecounter}]
}{%
\endlist
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ex}
One two three One two three One two three One two three
One two three One two three One two three One two three
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```